# Creating Dynamic Links Through DB and CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to take my result set and send it to the view so that it can be displayed accordingly and I"m having problems understanding the docs found here I have a template view of what I'd like it to somehow display like: That just gives you an idea. Below the template or what not is the code for my controller and the model that gets the category names from the database. Also is included is what I have currently for my view (php syntax is wrong).

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul class="clear">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><?php echo anchor('cpanel/modules/articles', 'Articles'); ?></li>
            <li><a href="styles.html">Styles</a></li>
            <li><a href="tables.html">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="charts.html">Charts</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Image Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $data = $this->Dashboard->get_user_info($id);
    $rows = $this->Dashboard->get_menu_categories();
    $this->template->set_layout('cpanel')->enable_parser(false);
    $this->template->set('data', $data);
    $this->template->set('menu_categories', $rows);
    $this->template->set_partial('header', 'partials/header');  
    $this->template->set_partial('sidebar', 'partials/sidebar');  
    $this->template->set_partial('content', 'partials/content');      
    $this->template->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer');
    $this->template->build('/cpanel/index');
}
```

Model:

```
/**
 * Get menu categories
 *
 * @param   none
 * @param   none
 * @return  object
 */
function get_menu_categories()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('menu_categories');
    $this->db->where('status_id', '1');
    $this->db->order_by('sort_order', 'desc'); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $row = $query->result_array(); 
}
```

View:

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul class="clear">
            <?php
            foreach ($row as $row)
            {
               echo "<li>" anchor('".$row['linkURL']."', '$row['category_name']')"</li>";
            }
            ?>                
        </ul>
    </div>
```

EDIT: Here is my new code. I"m getting the following error message: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: rows

Filename: partials/header.php

Line Number: 34
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: partials/header.php

Line Number: 34

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $data = $this->Dashboard->get_user_info($id);
    $menu_data['rows'] = $this->Dashboard->get_menu_categories();
    $this->template->set_layout('cpanel')->enable_parser(false);
    $this->template->set('data', $data);
    $this->template->set('menu_categories', $menu_data);

    $this->template->set_partial('header', 'partials/header');  
    $this->template->set_partial('sidebar', 'partials/sidebar');  
    $this->template->set_partial('content', 'partials/content');      
    $this->template->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer');
    $this->template->build('/cpanel/index');
}
```

Model:

```
/**
 * Get menu categories
 *
 * @param   none
 * @param   none
 * @return  object
 */
function get_menu_categories()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('menu_categories');
    $this->db->where('status_id', '1');
    $this->db->order_by('sort_order', 'desc'); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

View

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul class="clear">
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row)
            {
                echo '<li>'.anchor($row['category_name'], $row['category_name']).'</li>';
            }
            ?>                
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: In view: foreach (**$rows** as $row)

Comment: You should specify and link to docs when you are using third party libraries like the Template lib you seem to have, it would take a lot of the guess work out of answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line of `get_menu_categories()` to `return $query->result_array();`, the `$row` variable here does not affect the return value or do anything outside the scope of the function.

Assuming that `$this->template->set()` takes an associative array as the second parameter, which is likely the case, change it to:

```
$menu_data['rows'] = $this->Dashboard->get_menu_categories();
//          ^^^^ This is your variable name to be used in the view
$this->template->set('menu_categories', $menu_data);
```

Then you should be able to access `$rows` from the `menu_categories` view:

As noted in the comments, use `$rows` with an *s*:

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
   echo '<li>'.anchor($row['linkURL'], $row['category_name']).'</li>';
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a error message saying Trying to get property of non-object on the foreach loop on the partial view.

Comment: With this exact code? Makes no sense, it's not trying to access an object property, but rather an array value.

Comment: nvm the true errors is this: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: rows

Filename: partials/header.php

Line Number: 34
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: partials/header.php

Line Number: 34

Comment: You have to apply this logic to *every* instance where you assign data to a view. Use an associative array.

Comment: So your last comment confused me.

Comment: You have to assign data like this: `$local_var['view_file_var_name'] = $actual_value`

Comment: Right here: `$menu_data['rows'] = $this->Dashboard->get_menu_categories();`