# Undefined Variable footer_links

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason I’m getting an undefined variable on the view and not quite sure why. When I do a print_r of the variable of footer_links it shows up fine as such:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [link_name] => Home [short_name] => index ) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136271/creating-dynamic-links-through-db-and-ci) => stdClass Object ( [link_name] => About Us [short_name] => about-us ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [link_name] => Site Map [short_name] => site-map ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [link_name] => Contact-Us [short_name] => contact-us ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [link_name] => News Feed [short_name] => news-feed ) )

I know I'm not passing the variable in but when I tried it with the build it didn't work. Not sure why I should be passing it in. I'm using Phil Sturgeon's template library.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: footer_links

Filename: v1/footer.php

Line Number: 4
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: v1/footer.php

Line Number: 4
```

Controller:

```
$activeTemplate = $this->kow->getTemplate(); 
$siteInfo = $this->kow->getSiteTitleAndSlogan(); 
$footer_links = $this->kow->getFooterNav(); 
$this->template
     ->title($siteInfo[0]->site_name,$siteInfo[0]->site_slogan)
     ->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/css/'.$activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'.css" />')
     ->set_partial('header', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/header')
     ->set_partial('footer', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/footer')
     ->build('kow');
```

View:

```
<div id="footer">

    <ul>
       <?php foreach($footer_links as $row)
        {
        ?>
        <li><a><?php echo $row->link_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>  
    </ul>

    <p>&copy;COPYRIGHT 2010 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>

</div>
```

EDIT:

I found this stackoverflow question which is the same sort of deal I'm working with.
[Creating Dynamic Links Through DB and CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136271/creating-dynamic-links-through-db-and-ci)

Controller:

```
$activeTemplate = $this->kow->getTemplate(); 
$siteInfo = $this->kow->getSiteTitleAndSlogan(); 
$footer_links['rows'] = $this->kow->getFooterNav(); 
$this->template
->title($siteInfo[0]->site_name,$siteInfo[0]->site_slogan)
->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/css/'.$activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'.css" />')
->set('footer', $footer_links)            
->set_partial('header', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/header')
->set_partial('footer', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/footer')
->build('kow');
```

Model:

```
function getFooterNav()
{
    $this->db->select('site_menu_structures_links.link_name,site_menu_structures_links.short_name');
    $this->db->from('site_menu_structures_links');
    $this->db->join('site_menu_structures', 'site_menu_structures.id = site_menu_structures_links.menu_structure_id');
    $this->db->where('site_menu_structures.short_name', 'footernav'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

View:

```
<div id="footer">

    <ul>
       <?php foreach($rows as $row)
        {
        ?>
        <li><a><?php echo $row->link_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>  
    </ul>

    <p>&copy;COPYRIGHT 2010 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the template engine you're using but how are you passing your variable to your view? Are you doing the `print_r` inside the controller (of course here it will show) or view? Try putting `var_dump($footer_links); exit;` as the first line in your footer.php file.

Comment: Have a good look at the first codeblock of the person answering that question. I believe that's what you are doing wrong. Is it working now? Please post the errors (if any) now that you've changed it.